# Count of solutions to matrix equations

Tags: matrices, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gaussian-elimination

Given these modular equations:

$$a_{1,1} x_1 + a_{1,2} x_2 + \cdots + a_{1,n} x_n = b_1 \bmod p $$
$$a_{2,1} x_1 + a_{2,2} x_2 + \cdots + a_{2,n} x_n = b_2 \bmod p $$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{m,1} x_1 + a_{m,2} x_2 + \cdots + a_{m,n} x_n = b_m \bmod p $$

Imagine that all $a_{ij}$ and $b_k$ are given, along with $p$, a prime number.

Also assume that all $a$, $x$, and $b$ are less than $p$.

The only variables we don't know are the $x$ variables. How many solutions are there to this and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ is a field, the discussion is the same as in any field. Let $r$ be the rank of the left-hand side. Then $r\le \min(m,n)$ and:

- If the bordered matrix has rank $r$, the solutions are in bijection with $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^{n-r}$, so there are $p^{n-r}$ of them.
- If the bordered matrix has rank $>r$, the compatibility conditions are not all satisfied, hence there is no solution.

The answer would be the same for any finite field with $q$ element ($q=p^t$  for some prime $p$).

Comment: I'm sure you are correct and that this is a great answer, but I am unfamiliar with most of the words you are using. Is there a more "plain English" way to phrase the same thing? I'm not sure what you mean by "field" or "bordered matrix" or "bijection" etc.

Comment: Also, is the rank of a matrix something I can do for general $m,n$?

Comment: Absolutely; Gauß's row reduction is a general technique, valid in any field.

Comment: How can the rank of the matrix be $>r$? I must have misunderstood how rank is determined.

Comment: It is the *bordered* matrix which can have rank $>r$: it has one more column, and the row rank is equal to the column rank. Thus it can have rank $r+1$. It just means all the  compatibility conditions are not satisfied. Is it clear?

Comment: So you're saying it has no solutions if the rank is $r+1$?